# Process array in PHP parallely using pcntl_fork()

Tags: php, arrays, fork, pcntl

I am trying to achieve a task where I need to process an array of strings parallely after breaking it down into chunks.

I have an array of size 3000, where I need to break it down into multiple arrays of size 100.

I achieved it using:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($keywords,100); // $keywords is my array of size 3000
```

Now I have a method called `process` where I need to process each chunk(smaller array of size 100).

```
public function process($chunk){
    foreach($chunk as $keyword){
        // Process the single keyword...
    }
}
```

But the above task is to be achieved in such a way that every chunk is processed parallely... 
My entire script is:

```
<?php
    public function readKeywords(){
        $keywords = array();

        // code to read a file and populate the array $keywords

        return $keywords;
    }

    public function process($chunk){
        foreach($chunk as $keyword){
            // Process the single keyword...
        }
    } 

    public function init($chunks,$index = 0){
        $pid = pcntl_fork();

        if($pid === -1){
            // Couldn't fork
        } else if($pid){
            process($chunks[$index]);
        }else{
            $index++;
            if(count($chunks) > $index){
                 process($chunks,$index);
            }
        }
    }

    public function start($keywords){
        $chunks = array_chunk($keywords,100);
        init($chunks);
    }


    $keywords = readKeywords();
    start($keywords);
?>
```

Now the challenge is, if I have 3000 keywords in the array, and if I break it down in chunks of 100, I will have 30 active processes to process each chunk.

So I need to `pause` creating chunks when `3` processes are active. If any `1` of the `3` processes completes, the recursion should happen again and a new child process should be created and the next chunk should be processed. This will increase the execution time, but it is OK.

So to limit the number of processes, I tried the following code but with no luck:

```
public void init($chunks){
    $pids = array();

    for($i = 0;$i < 3;$i++){
        $pid = pcntl_fork();  
        if($pid === -1){
             // Couldn't fork
        } else if($pid){
            process($chunks[$i]);
        }else{
            exit();
        }
    }

    for($i = 0;$i < count($pids);$i++){
        pcntl_waitpid($pids[$i],$status,WUNTRACED); // Read somewhere that it waits  till it's child process has completed execution
    }

    if($index < count($chunks)) // If there are chunks remaining to be processed {
        $newChunks = array();
        for($i = 3;$i < count($chunks);$i++){
            $newChunks[] = $chunks[$i];
        }
        init($newChunks);
    }
}
```

Have been working out a lot, but no luck. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `exec('ps -C '.$filename, $processes);`, then count the `$processes` to check how many of them are running

Comment: No. Not clean. Need to do it via code. Any other solution?